# Передача опции select в запрос

Tags: база-данных, php, mysql

Здравствуйте. Столкнулся с такой проблемой, что при выборе опции в селекте, меняются значения, которые я просто напросто не трогал.

```
    if(isset($_POST['sumbitprof']))
{

switch($_POST['sucp'])
{
    case '0':
    {
        $tt = "1";
    }
    case '1':
    {
        $tt = "0";
    }
}
switch($_POST['slic'])
{
    case '0':
    {
        $ll = "1";
    }
    case '1':
    {
        $ll = "0";
    }   
}
switch($_POST['sskil'])
{
    case '0':
    {
        $xx = "1";
    }
    case '1':
    {
        $xx = "0";
    }
}
    $mquery = sprintf("UPDATE `Accounts` SET `Noshowucp`='%d',`Noshowlic`='%d',`Noshowskills`='%d' WHERE `NickName`='%s'",$tt,$ll,$xx,$nickname);
    $mysqli->query($mquery);
    echo '<META HTTP-EQUIV="REFRESH" CONTENT="2;/settings&go=global">';
    exit("<div id='status_action'><p><b style='color:#006400;'>SUCCES: Сохранено успешно</b></p></div>");
}   
if($row['Noshowucp']==0)
{
$checkucp = "selected";
}else{
$checkucp = "";
}

if($row['Noshowlic']==0)
{
$checklics = "selected";
}else{
$checklics = "";
}

if($row['Noshowskills']==0)
{
$checkskils = "selected";
}else{
$checkskils = "";
}

    echo '<form method="post">';
    echo "<div class='donatecont'><div class='donatecontp'><div class='donateleft'><b>Скрыть статистику Вашего игрового персонажа:</b>";
    echo "</div>";
    echo "<div class='donateright'>";
    echo "
    <select name='sucp'>
    <option value='0' ".$checkucp.">Скрывать</option>
    <option value='1' ".$checkucp.">Не скрывать</option>
    </select>       
    ";
    echo "</div></div>";
    echo "<div class='donatecontp'><div class='donateleft'><b>Скрыть лицензии Вашего игрового персонажа:</b>";
    echo "</div>";
    echo "<div class='donateright'>";
    echo "
    <select name='slic'>
    <option value='0' ".$checklics.">Скрывать</option>
    <option value='1' ".$checklics.">Не скрывать</option>
    </select>       
    ";
    echo "</div></div>";
    echo "<div class='donatecontp'><div class='donateleft'><b>Скрыть скилы Вашего игрового персонажа:</b>";
    echo "</div>";
    echo "<div class='donateright'>";
    echo "
    <select name='sskil'>
    <option value='0' ".$checkskils.">Скрывать</option>
    <option value='1' ".$checkskils.">Не скрывать</option>
    </select>       
    ";
    echo "</div></div></div>";
    echo '<input type="submit" value="Сохранить" name="sumbitprof" />';
    echo '</form>';
```

Помогите пожалуйста разобраться с проблемой. Заранее спасибо!

Comment: хе-хе =)) я тоже раньше вместо submit писал sumbit =))

Answer (score 3):

Ну во-первых я бы посоветовал выучить синтаксис switch

Comment: А в чем проблема то в коде?

Comment: в неправильном синтаксисе. почитай, как switch работает, все поймешь